# Creating screenshot with AutoIt _ScreenCapture_Capture in remote server does not work

Tags: windows, scripting, screenshot, autoit

I have a farm of virtual windows servers and they are autonomously running various desktop applications and I want to have easy way to see what's going on on each server without connecting through RDP. So I have created a simple AutoIt script which automatically runs every minute and creates a screenshot of **virtual servers desktop**:

```
#NoTrayIcon
#include <WinAPI.au3>
#include <ScreenCapture.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

$LocalIP = _getLocalIP()
_ScreenCapture_Capture($CmdLine[1] & "\network\shared\screenshot_" & $LocalIP & ".jpg")
```

...

The problem I am having is that screenshot only displays desktop with apps when I am connected to it through RDP, once I close it - screenshot will appear black and only **mouse pointer is visible**.

**Is there any way I can create screenshot even if RDP session is closed? Is that possible?**

Comment: to clarify, user sessions are active, they are logged in.

Comment: Sounds to me you are making screenshots of the desktop for scheduled tasks.  Yes, nothing on it.

Comment: It's possible that Windows is not rendering those applications you expect to see, because it knows that no one is looking. (Yes, Windows is sneaky like that)

Comment: The presence of the cursor can be explained in the code of the _ScreenCapture_Capture function, it is added later on using, probably, last known coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in previous replies - this is probably due to the machine being locked.
You can try to use a script that will unlock the remote station, and then perform a screen capture.
Have a look at [this post in autoit forum](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/53154-unlock-a-locked-xp-machine/page__mode__threaded)